# How to combine text message with system message?

Tags: command-line, pipe, date, command

For example, I want to write a command that shows the system time&date.

Then I want the output be like this

`The system time is  Mon Jan 01 01:01:01 AST 2011.`

I know the command that shows the system time is `date` but how to add `"The system time is"` at the front of the output?

should it be `echo The system time is + %#%@^ + date` stuff like that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple way would be:

```
printf "The system time is %s.\n" "$(date)"
```

You could also use string interpolation:

```
echo "The system time is $(date)."
```

Answer (score 12):

With GNU date:

```
date +"The system time is %a %b %d %T %Z %Y"
```

Comment: +1 for this because it's a single command rather than two.

Comment: @MontyHarder: `echo` isn't really a command, though...

Comment: What would you call `echo`, @seaturtle ? Perhaps "an often built-in, but sometimes external command"?

Comment: Do any (relatively common) shells _not_ have `echo` as a builtin? I thought it always was.

Comment: I just think we're splitting hairs if you don't call "built-in commands" "commands", but something else.

Comment: Regarding echo as a built-in, I believe it's common, but just went to look -- and it's [not POSIX-specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_06) to be built-in.

Comment: @seaturtle useless comment is useless... A builtin command is still a command. You can recognize that it is a command from ‚command‘ part in the expression ‚builtin _command_‘. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html

Comment: Relatively common - yes, should have echo as built in, but apparently Bourne shell didn't have echo as built in until 1979 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks everyone. (I shouldn't have used the word 'command' – I actually meant 'external command'. I should have been more clear.)

Answer (score 8):

Straightforwardly:

```
date +"The system time is %c"
```

- `%c` - locale's date and time

Comment: @Ulysses Unfortunately, you've already accepted another answer, apparently within an hour of asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

With Bash 4.2 and higher, you can use printf:

```
printf "The system time is %(%a %b %d %T %Z %Y)T\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the old days, we did

```
echo The system time is `date`.
```

But the backticks for command substitution are deprecated these days. Use this instead

```
echo The system time is $(date).
```

(only 1 extra character to type). You don't need no stinking double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Trivially:

```
echo -n 'The system time is '; date
```

Requires `echo` that honours the `-n` switch, but you'd have to search deep to find a system where it does not (or use `printf`).